# Thousands of threads spawned from Java process... why?

Tags: java, multithreading, blockingqueue

I have a problem with a recent customer migration to Linux (64-bit) when running a Java process.

The process is spawning thousands of threads most with an identifier of futex. I've looked up futex (fast userspace mutex) and it's a Linux construct to implement basic locking.

The code has recently changed to implement a BlockingQueue and an ExecutorService to spawn child threads but the number of child threads is controlled by a config setting and I can prove that this specific mechanism is not running out of control. I can only assume that something internal to the JVM is spawning all these threads due to the BlockingQueue and some lock?

So can anyone tell me how to find out what these threads actually are and what I might do to control/stop them?

Below is a few lines of the process list; the actual list before the process had to be killed was over 13000 lines long.

0 - 54321   447   446  1   -   - - 5953085 -    ?        00:15:50 java
0 S 54321     -     -  0  82   2 -     - futex_ -        00:00:00 -
1 S 54321     -     -  0  82   2 -     - futex_ -        00:00:00 -
1 S 54321     -     -  0  82   2 -     - futex_ -        00:00:00 -
1 S 54321     -     -  0  82   2 -     - futex_ -        00:00:00 -
1 S 54321     -     -  0  82   2 -     - futex_ -        00:00:00 -
1 S 54321     -     -  0  82   2 -     - futex_ -        00:00:00 -
1 S 54321     -     -  0  82   2 -     - futex_ -        00:00:00 -
1 S 54321     -     -  0  82   2 -     - futex_ -        00:00:00 -

Any suggestions gratefully accepted.

Comment: Can you take a thread dump?  BlockingQueue and Lock do not create threads or cause more to be created. Only a mis-configured ExecutorService could do this or a loop creating Threads.

Comment: Which version of the JVM are you using?  I've had colleagues have problems with 64bit JVM under Windows, where it would consume up all the system resources, an apparent bug in the JVM.  If the same exact code does cause problems under 32bit, it may likely be a 64bit JVM problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot load the application in the debugger of an IDE, you might want to load the application with VisualVM to look at what the threads are actually doing:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/threads.html

Make sure you can kill the app, as it might run out of resources because of the high number of threads (i.e. in linux, have a shell ready).